# Information theory problem, sets of numbers

Tags: compression, computer-science

I only have 32 bits of space to store a combination of items. The constraints are that a combination can have anywhere from 0 to 7 items. There are 64 unique items. An item cannot appear multiple times in a combination.

How do I map these sets of items to 32-bit integers?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to assume that by a "combination" you mean a set. The ordering of a set does not matter. If the ordering matters, then the possibilities cannot fit in 32 bits.

For set of 0 to 7 elements, where there are 64 possible elements, we have that there are the sum of binomial(64,i) for i in 0..7 possibilities, which is 704,494,193. That would even fit in 30 bits (2<sup>30</sup> = 1,073,741,824).

Simply define a scheme that numbers each possibility uniquely and store that number. E.g. assign 0 for zero elements, 1..64 for one element, 65..2080 for two elements, and so on.

Comment: Note that the itertools documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) gives a recipe for finding the nth combination.

Answer (score 0):

nth_combination comes from the itertools recipes ([at the bottom of this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)). It converts from the 32 bit number to a specific combination however, the inverse function is not included on the itertools recipes page. combination_index outlined below takes in the combination and returns the index of that combination.

These two functions can be used as a base to calculate an index into the power set. Which solves the original question, allowing r to range from 0 to 7. The index needs to be shifted by the total combinations of the previous combinations. The index shifting for r = 7 would add each of the previous combinations aka math.comb(64, 0) + math.comb(64, 1) + math.comb(64, 2) + math.comb(64, 3) + math.comb(64, 4) + math.comb(64, 5) + math.comb(64, 6).

```py
import math
import itertools

# this is the inverse of the nth_combination function
# aka. combination_index("abcd", nth_combination("abcd", 2, 3)) returns 3
def combination_index(iterable, combination):
    # combination must be sorted in the same order as the iterable 
    # r must be less than or equal to n
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = len(combination)
    
    result = 0
    index = 0
    for i, item in enumerate(pool):
        if (item != combination[index]):
            result += math.comb(n - i - 1, r - index - 1)
        else:
            index += 1
        if (index >= len(combination)):
            break
    return result
```